# Is it possible to freeze salad dressing

Tags: salad

Is it ok to freeze Vinegarette Dressings.  Need to take on a flight for a friend.  Label says keep refrigerated so would this be ok for a 12hr flt in checked luggage in a insulated freezer bag.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this a commercial dressing? Unopened?

Comment: should be ok. must be an exceptional commercial dressing to bring to a friend over plane travel !!

Comment: You should remember that freezing liquids often breaks the container. A post on outdoors stack exchange tells [how to avoid this](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/how-to-freeze-a-water-container-without-deforming-it/9597#9597)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the ingredients are other than oil and vinegar, the tolerance to freezing is flexible. I would err on the side of caution and wrap the bottle/container twice in bubble wrap so that the ice or cold packs don't directly contact the container. That way, you still get excellent cooling while greatly reducing the risk of damage or separating of the dressing from direct freezing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be fine.

Are you worried the freezer bag will freeze the vinaigrette?  There is not enough cold in a freezer bag to freeze it.  And the freezing point of vinaigrette is lower than water.

Pack it in the middle of clothes.